I am trying to schedule an event in AWS Eventbridge using an HTTP request
Well, when I want to schedule an event that AWS Eventbridge will manage, I have a problem.
defmodule MyApp.SchedulerSqs do
  @moduledoc false
  def event_schedule(name, schedule_expression, ftw, arn, rolearn) do
    url = "https://events.us-east-2.amazonaws.com"
    headers = [
      "Content-Type": "application/x-amz-json-1.1",
      "X-Amz-Target": "AWSEvents.PutRule"
    ]
    targets = %{
      "Arn": arn,
      "RoleArn": rolearn
    }
    body = %{
      "Name": name,
      "ScheduleExpression": schedule_expression,
      "FlexibleTimeWindows": ftw,
      "Targets": [targets]
    } |> Jason.encode!()

    {:ok, %{body: response}} = HTTPoison.post(url, body, headers, [])
    response
  end
end

I enter the data through the console
MyApp.SchedulerSqs.event_schedule(
    "MyScheduledEvent",
    "cron(0/10 * * * ? *)",
    %{mode: "OFF"},
    "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-2:xxxxxxxxxxxxx:queuedefault.fifo",
    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/MyEventBridgeRole"
)

Result:
"{\"__type\":\"MissingAuthenticationTokenException\",\"message\":\"Missing Authentication Token\"}"

I would appreciate it if someone with knowledge in AWS could help me a little.
I made some changes
    config = ExAws.Config.new(:events)

    {:ok, signed_headers} = Auth.headers(config, :post, url, headers, body, service)

    {:ok, %{body: response}} = HTTPoison.post(url, body, signed_headers, [])
    response

I was using ex_aws library for authentication but I have this problem although the problem has more to do with elixir than with aws
** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: {:error, "Required key: :secret_access_key not found in config!"}
    (my_app 0.1.0) lib/my_app/scheduler.ex:24: MyApp.Scheduler.event_schedule/5

But in my environment variables I do have them added
config :ex_aws,
  access_key_id: [{:system, "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"}, {:awscli, "default", 30}],
  secret_access_key: [{:system, "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"},{:awscli, "default, 30"}],
  region: {:system, "AWS_REGION"}


Please add a language tag and I'd recommend removing scheduler as this isn't a question about scheduling, it's a question about AWS authentication
